# How to make pure CSS dropdown menu appear with a fade in/slowly

Tags: html, css, menu

As the title suggest, I'm trying to make a pure CSS drop down menu. The only thing is I cannot get the dropdown to fade in slowly no matter what I've tried.

Here's the JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/UWgCV/

FYI It's not my terrible code, it's from the previous designer who abandoned the project.

Thanks.

edit: I need to accompany this post with code because of the jsfiddlet link, so here is the menu.

```
    <li><a href="/emergencyservices/whatwedo.php" accesskey="3" title="">EMERGENCY SERVICE &nbsp; &nbsp;|</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="/emergencyservices/whatwedo.php">&nbsp;What We Do</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/emergencyservices/howstaffed.php">&nbsp;How We Are Staffed</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/emergencyservices/referralemerghandling.php">&nbsp;Emergency/Referral Procedure&nbsp;</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/emergencyservices/typesofemerg.php">&nbsp;Types of Emergencies</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/emergencyservices/whattoexpect.php">&nbsp;What to Expect On Arrival</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: No need to excuse for the terrible code, but rather for the fact that there's no attempt of creating the slow fade... in that code. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using something like
transition:color 1s ease-in-out 500ms, background-color 1s ease-in-out 500ms;
-webkit-transition:color 1s ease-in-out 500ms, background-color 1s ease-in-out 500ms

But to be honest, this is new territory to me. I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CSS3 Animations, although they aren't supported in all browsers such as <=IE9, this is exactly what they were made for. You may want to try jQuery for older browsers.

**Workign demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWgCV/1/)**

```
li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 98;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```